# Can you reference a non-static method in a static context?

Tags: c#, .net

Use of delegates follows the same rules as calling methods - you can only refer to a method via a delegate if you are allowed to call that method explicitly, which means you cannot reference a non-static method from a static method, even if you don't actually call it.  Is there a way around that?

Here is some code used in performing the Bowling Kata, with my ideal lines of code shown in comments.  I was forced to go through a static call (and anonymous static method declarations) to make the Frame Class code declarative to my liking:

```
    public int FrameScore()
    {
        return scorer[FrameType()](this);
        // I would like it to be
        // return this.scorer[FrameType()]();
    }

    static Dictionary<LinkedFrame.FrameTypeEnum, Func<LinkedFrame, int>> scorer =
        new Dictionary<LinkedFrame.FrameTypeEnum, Func<LinkedFrame, int>>()
        {
            {LinkedFrame.FrameTypeEnum.Strike, frame => frame.StrikeScore()},
            {LinkedFrame.FrameTypeEnum.Spare, frame => frame.SpareScore()},
            {LinkedFrame.FrameTypeEnum.Regular, frame => frame.RegularScore()}
            // I would like an element to be
            // {LinkedFrame.FrameTypeEnum.Strike, StrikeScore}
        };

    private int RegularScore()
    {
        return this.Sum;
    }

    private int SpareScore()
    {
        ...
    }

    private int StrikeScore()
    {
        ...
    }
```

So in some contexts it would make sense to reason about non-static methods in a static context.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Have you considered a simple `switch` statement in your FrameScore method?

Comment: You *can* refer to non-static methods from a static context, what you can not do is refer to methods on `this`, because there is no `this`. You can work around that by explicitly passing a this-like parameter, but then you might as well make that method non-static.

Comment: Initializing the (non-static) dictionary in the constructor will work.  Very inefficient of course.  What you need are the equivalent of member function pointers in C++.  Supported in C++/CLI as "unbound delegates", not in C#.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe open instance delegates will help?

According to [MSDN: Delegate Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate%28v=VS.100%29.aspx):

> When a delegate represents an instance method closed over its first argument (the most common case), the delegate stores a reference to the method's entry point and a reference to an object, called the target, which is of a type assignable to the type that defined the method. When a delegate represents an open instance method, it stores a reference to the method's entry point. The delegate signature must include the hidden this parameter in its formal parameter list; in this case, the delegate does not have a reference to a target object, and a target object must be supplied when the delegate is invoked.

What it comes down to, is that you can sneakily convert an instance method to a static method with an explicit `this` parameter. You can see how it's done here: [Simon Cooper: Introduction to open instance delegates](http://www.simple-talk.com/community/blogs/simonc/archive/2010/07/28/93676.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

An instance method always requires an instance to be invoked with.

If you want to invoke an instance method through a delegate, you have two options:

1. The delegate captures the instance in some way.
2. You need to pass the instance to the delegate.

You seem to want to have a delegate that does not capture an instance and does not require an instance to be passed. That's not possible in C#.